# Where does SNMP OIDs get the data from?

Tags: snmp

If I want to find out network traffic on my Linux Servers using SNMP. I use the ifOutOctets. and ifInOctets. OIDs in an snmpget request. Where do these OIDs get the data from?

I tried looking at the rfc for these OIDs but I'm still none the wiser. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3635#section-3.2.5

Comment: I hope this would be helpful;  http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-snmp-oids-for-cpumemory-and-disk-statistics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  For `ifOutOctets` and `ifInOctets`, `snmpd` probably gets them by querying the kernel (either directly via a syscall or perhaps by examining `/proc/net/dev`).

For other OIDs, it may get them by running an external command to extract and process the data before returning it.  e.g. see [Extending snmpd using shell scripts](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts) for examples.

Comment: On Ubuntu at least, ifOutOctets and ifInOctets references the data from /proc/net/dev file. This can be verified using `strace -p <pid Of SNMP> -e trace=open`